# ES6 will be only executed on IE/Edge when Developer-Tools enabled

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ecmascript-6, microsoft-edge

When i try to experiment with `ES6`, Opera and Chrome will run these.
But when i try to check out Internet Explorer or Edge (on Windows 10), IE/Edge will only execute these, when i have opened the Developer-Tools (F12).

`!html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DEV</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="/base/Client.class.js"></script>
        <script>new Client();</script>
    </body>
</html>`

`javascript
export default class Start {
    constructor() {
        console.log('TEST!');
    }
}`

When i'm opening the Developer-Tools **after** loading, Edge shows following Errors:

> TypeError: Invalid calling object.

How i can fix these and why will the code only executed by IE/Edge, when the DevTools are opened?

Comment: I see an export, but I don't see an import.

Comment: Just use Babel - that's what it's for: transpiling ES6+ down to the platforms that don't have all the features.